# TypeError when trying to get a dictionary from a website

Tags: python, dictionary

I am trying to get tv guide info with the following code. however I get TypeError: string indices must be integers.

Any help would be very useful.

```
import requests

url="https://www.digiturk.com.tr/_Services/TVguide/jProxy.aspx?cid=271&sd=13_4_2020_0_0"
html_content = requests.get(url).text
remove_copy="/*Copyright © 2009 Digital Platform İletişim Hizmetleri A.Ş. Tüm Hakları Saklıdır. Bu servisin izinsiz kullanımından doğacak tüm yasal yükümlülükleri izinsiz kullanan kişiler kabul etmiş sayılır.*/"
page_content=html_content.split(remove_copy)[-1]
null="null"

for ch in f["BChannels"]:
    for pr in ch["CPrograms"]:
        print(pr["PName"], pr["POName"], pr["BID"], pr["PDuration"])
```

Comment: The error message you are getting is because you are trying to access some string like ch using a string like 'CPrograms' instead of accessing by integer index like ch[0] or ch[100]. The code you posted is not completed because variables f and ch that you you in loops are not even defined in your code snippet

Comment: does my answer help you? if so, click the tick next to it so that the question is closed

Answer (score 0):

> `page_content=html_content.split(remove_copy)[-1]`

`page_content` is a string. You have to parse it in order to use it as a dict:

```py
import json
...
page_content = json.loads(html_content.split(remove_copy)[-1])
...
for ch in page_content["BChannels"]:
    for pr in ch["CPrograms"]:
        print(pr["PName"], pr["POName"], pr["BID"], pr["PDuration"])
```

```
DERİN SULAR SUBMERGENCE 1048340359 6285
AZ SONRA...  1048340614 622
YEŞİL REHBER GREEN BOOK 1048340360 7458
AZ SONRA...  1048446330 934
AQUAMAN  1048446078 8245
AZ SONRA...  1048446329 1027
EVCİL HAYVANLARIN GİZLİ...2 THE SECRET LIFE OF PETS 2, THE ( 1048446287 4947
AZ SONRA...  1048446328 1056
KINGS Kings 1048446079 4887
AZ SONRA...  1048446327 1149
PARAZİT PARASITE 1048446285 7486
AZ SONRA...  1048446326 1482
HIRSIZLAR KRALI KING OF THIEVES 1048446080 6197
AZ SONRA...  1048446325 1352
VOX LUX  1048446081 6546
AZ SONRA...  1048446331 923
10x10  1048446082 4813
AZ SONRA...  1048446324 594
TULLY  1048446083 5485
AZ SONRA...  1048446323 3526
PARAZİT PARASITE 1048446295 7486
AZ SONRA...  1048446332 313
HIRSIZLAR KRALI KING OF THIEVES 1048446084 6650
```

Comment: I will remove my answer, we were writing in the same time

Comment: Thank you so much for the help :)

Answer (score -1):

Try:

```
import requests

url="https://www.digiturk.com.tr/_Services/TVguide/jProxy.aspx?cid=271&sd=13_4_2020_0_0"
html_content = requests.get(url).text
remove_copy="/*Copyright © 2009 Digital Platform İletişim Hizmetleri A.Ş. Tüm Hakları Saklıdır. Bu servisin izinsiz kullanımından doğacak tüm yasal yükümlülükleri izinsiz kullanan kişiler kabul etmiş sayılır.*/"
page_content=html_content.split(remove_copy)[-1]
null="null"
f = eval(page_content)
for ch in f["BChannels"]:
    for pr in ch["CPrograms"]:
        print(pr["PName"], pr["POName"], pr["BID"], pr["PDuration"])
```

The `eval()` converts the string to dictionary so that it can be traversed through.
Instead of eval() the json library can also be used.  (need to import json using `import json` )
Change:

```
f = eval(page_content)
```

To:

```
f = json.loads(page_content)
```

Output:

```
DERİN SULAR SUBMERGENCE 1048340359 6285
AZ SONRA...  1048340614 622
YEŞİL REHBER GREEN BOOK 1048340360 7458
AZ SONRA...  1048446330 934
AQUAMAN  1048446078 8245
AZ SONRA...  1048446329 1027
EVCİL HAYVANLARIN GİZLİ...2 THE SECRET LIFE OF PETS 2, THE ( 1048446287 4947
AZ SONRA...  1048446328 1056
KINGS Kings 1048446079 4887
AZ SONRA...  1048446327 1149
PARAZİT PARASITE 1048446285 7486
AZ SONRA...  1048446326 1482
HIRSIZLAR KRALI KING OF THIEVES 1048446080 6197
AZ SONRA...  1048446325 1352
VOX LUX  1048446081 6546
AZ SONRA...  1048446331 923
10x10  1048446082 4813
AZ SONRA...  1048446324 594
TULLY  1048446083 5485
AZ SONRA...  1048446323 3526
PARAZİT PARASITE 1048446295 7486
AZ SONRA...  1048446332 313
HIRSIZLAR KRALI KING OF THIEVES 1048446084 6650
```

Comment: I didn't downvote you answer. Though my remark about eval, remains...